# How to concatenate vectors to create a array in loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a loop `for` that generate a new vector `(100,)` in each iteration.  So the code loop likes

```
for i in range (10):
   for j in range (4):
     #Create a new vector (100,) 
     #Concatenate 4 vector together to make (400,) #400=4*10 
#Append the concatenation vectors (400,) in vertical to make (10,400) array
```

My expected is that generates a matrix size of `(10,400)` that concatenate vectors in these loops

Currently, my solution is

```
   matrix_= np.empty([10,400])
    for i in range (10):
       vector_horz=[]
       for j in range (4):
         #Create a new vector (100,) 
         vector_rnd=#Random make a vector/list with size of (100,1)
         #Concatenate 4 vector together to make (400,) #400=4*10
         vector_horz.append(vector_rnd)
    #Append the concatenation vectors (400,) in vertical to make (10,400) array
       matrix_(:,i)=vector_horz
```

However, it said that my size of `matrix` and `vector_horz` cannot assign. Could you give me another solution?

Comment: I don't believe this is enough information to answer your question. How about a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, I have to update it. It may missing some sentence

Comment: Just a note, it's extremely inefficient to continually append to `numpy` arrays. This involves repeated memory reallocation. Instead, declare the size of the array when you instantiate it, then fill it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I have updated it, Please look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
(Recommended) First generate your data and create an array at the end:

```
data = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(4):
        temp_list = ... # random vector of 100 elements 
        data.extend(temp_list) 

arr = np.reshape(data, (10, 400))
```

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, initialise an empty array with `np.empty` and assign one slice at a time:

```
arr = np.empty((10, 400))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(4):
        temp_list = ...
        arr[i, j * 100 : (j + 1) * 100] = temp_list
```